# Google App Engine Flex Throws 502 After adding Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-flexible

I have an app running on App Engine Flex (Google Go Runtime with a couple extra file in the docker runtime). It was working fine, with no issues.

I then added Google Cloud Endpoints and all of a sudden I was getting 502s for every request, both going directly to the app & going through Cloud Endpoints.

Logging into the instance, it looks like the nginx-proxy itself is throwing errors.

```
Downloading Endpoints Service Configuration to /etc/nginx/endpoints/service.json
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
Failed to obtain Endpoints Service Configuration from Service Management API
/sbin/start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 26: No such process
```

The only addition to the app.yaml is

```
endpoints_api_service:
   name: "redacted.appspot.com"
   config_id: "2017-06-01r0"
```

I'm running the latest version of gcloud. I was getting 403 forbidden when deploying the openapi.yaml file, and then I updated to the latest gcloud which fixed that issue. Not sure if that's related or not.

Has anyone even encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the core issue was that the version of gcloud I first used to upload google cloud endpoints allowed me to use an unsupported parameter (File). After switching to a wildcard, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

From Cloud Console UI, could you double check if your project has "Google Service Management API" enabled?

If already enabled, you can SSH into your Flex vm,  and fetch the access token by:

curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token

Then you can use this URL to check its scopes

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=